# Multiple Router Outlets on Same HTML Page

Tags: angular

In Angular 8, I'm trying to set up multiple router outlets on my HTML page so that different web pages can be with 1 page. Please take a look my code and help. Thank you!

app.component.html:

```
<div style="background-color: green;">
  <router-outlet>
  </router-outlet>
</div>

<div style="background-color:red">
  <router-outlet name="betapage">
  </router-outlet>
</div>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AlphaComponent } from './alpha/alpha.component'
import { BetaComponent } from './beta/beta.component'

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AlphaComponent },
  { path: 'beta', component: BetaComponent, outlet: 'betapage' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

alpha.component.html:

```
<p>
  alpha works!
</p>
```

beta.component.html:

```
<p>
  beta works!
</p>
```

When I run the application, only "alpha works!" shows up and not "beta works!".

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to navigate to ?

Comment: localhost:4200/

Comment: just covering all bases here, but did you try localhost:4200/beta

Comment: Yes, I did but couldn't get it to show both "alpha works!" and "beta works!" on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Primary and secondary outlets are routed independently of each other, and can both be active at the same time by enclosing the secondary route within parenthesis in a URL.

Try to see if this works for you.

localhost:4200/(betapage:beta)